# How to find the Maclaurin series for the integral of $e^{x^2}$?

Tags: calculus, integration, power-series, exponential-function, taylor-expansion

I am trying to find the Maclaurin series for the integral of  $e^{x^2}$? What I done so far is that the Maclaurin series for $e^{x^2}$ is 
$$e^{x^2}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2n}}{n!}$$

So would the Maclaurin series simply be $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2n+1}}{n!(2n+1)}$? I am stumped and I don't know how to solve this, all help is appreciated.

Comment: That is exactly right, since an antiderivative of $x^{2n}/n!$ is $x^{2n+1}/(n!(2n+1))$.

Comment: You can get away with that manipulation so long as you have a *uniformly convergent* series, which you do. Don't forget the $+C$.

Comment: Thank you all for the response! Thanks, I forgot to put it on there @Spencer.